# Getting currency list item values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, listitem

I have a list that contain two colums which are type currency. I want to be able to read the values from this field with the decimal places and the currecy symbol included.

I have tried three different methods but I only seem to get the numbers and not the currecny symbol. Also decimal values are not being properly displayed. The columns that use the decimal type are "InstallCosts" and "RentalCosts".

```
foreach (SPListItem item in listItemCollection)
{
try
{
string MPLS;
if ((bool)item["MPLS"])
MPLS = "Yes";
else
MPLS = "No";

//Conversion 1
double installCost;
bool convert1 = double.TryParse(item["InstallCosts"].ToString(), out installCost);

double rentalCost;
bool convert2 = double.TryParse(item["RentalCosts"].ToString(), out rentalCost);


//Conversion 2
string install = item["InstallCosts"].ToString();
double installConverted = double.Parse(install, NumberStyles.Currency,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);

//Conversion 3
//string converThis = String.Format("[0:c}", (string)item["InstallCosts"]);


string results56 = (string)item["Title"] + " " + (string)item["DefinedFor"] + " " +
"<b>MPLS:</b> " + MPLS + "<br/>" + "<b>Max Downstream:</b> " + 
(string)item["MaxDownstream"] + "<br/>" + "Install Cost:" + converThis + "<br/>" 
+ "Rental Cost (p.a.):" + rentalCost + "<br/>";

AvailabilityCheckerResultsTwo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(results56));
}
```

The result is the following:

Alpaca A dirty ADSL product for: CCTV third-party remote access interactive models and web site testing. MPLS: No
Max Downstream: 
Install Cost:50
Rental Cost (p.a.):425.7

The resuts for "Install Cost" should be : £50.00
The result for "Rental Cost" should be : £425.70

I have being stuck with this problem for a day now, would appreciate any assistance its probably something I am missing but I can't really see what!

Many Thanks,

Comment: Never use double for currency you will begin to see subtle loss due to precision of processing. Use decimal only.

Comment: `double less = 0.3; double more = 0.4; double diff = 0.1; return more - less == diff; // false!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net the numbers do not contain any currency or any other formatting information. So you have to add the currency symbol on your own:

```
SPListItem item = ...;
double d = Convert.ToDouble(item["InstallCosts"]);
// will display the number in the current threads culture. In the US: $ <value>
string currency = d.ToString("C");
```

Comment: beat me to it by a few seconds :) And as OmegaMan suggested using Decimal is normally best for currency. Not that I think in this scenario there would be a noticable difference.

Comment: Hey Stefan, Thanks alot that did the trick. it displays the values as they should be in their correct format eg. £50.00. Much appreciated